# How to make --exclude-glob work with this use case of lftp and fish shell?

Tags: linux, wildcards, fish, syntax, lftp

I have a statement that looks like this:

```
set cmd 'set ssl:verify-certificate false;
open -u abc,def ftp.somewhere.com;
mirror --only-newer --exclude-glob "{.git|node_modules|wp-config.php}" \
/public_html '"$argv"
```

and it is used in this statement:

```
lftp -c $cmd
```

The interesting thing is that `"{.git|node_modules|wp-config.php}"` does not stop the file `wp-config.php` from being put in the output dir.

Maybe I don't understand yet the syntax of fish well enough.

## Update 1

This question is abandoned because I succeeded in the same task using rclone inside fish. rclone is very popular on GitHub.

```
rclone sync html $RCLONE_REMOTE:$PUBLIC_HTML_PATH -P --log-file=$fn2 \
  --filter "- wp-content/themes/$THEME_NAME/node_modules/**" \
  --filter "- wp-content/themes/$THEME_NAME/vendor/**" \
  --filter "- wp-config.php" \
  --filter "+ wp-content/themes/$THEME_NAME/react-nav-bar/dist/**" \
  --filter "- wp-content/themes/$THEME_NAME/react-nav-bar/**"
```

Comment: my `lftp` does not have an `exclude-glob` option for mirror. It does have `exclude-regex`. And that pattern is not strictly a glob pattern (in bash, brace expansions are separate from globbing), but this is how lftp implements it, not fish.

Comment: @glennjackman I use `lftp` 4.9.2. What version of `lftp` do you have? Do you think that instead of `--exclude-glob "{.git|node_modules|wp-config.php}"` most probably I should use `--exclude-glob "(.git|node_modules|wp-config.php)"` (also notice the double quotes)? Thanks.

Comment: Same version, I don't see `--exclude-glob` in the man page. Perhaps the man page is not exhaustive. Anyway, apparently lftp does not honour the brace expression as a glob pattern. Try `mirror --exclude .git --exclude mode_modules --exclude wp-config.php`

Comment: I think that `--exclude-glob` is an option for the `mirror` command. At the start of the question I put the contents of a lftp script.